# Staging data validation using lookup in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I wanted do some master data validation on staging table like, Product not available, Store not available.. I need to use lookup as master tables are in different system. Please suggest how to handle no math output of lookup transformation to update it back to staging table which is source for lookup.

Awaiting reply..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use no match output property in lookup.

And insert the new record (not matched)

Note:  use lookup task in no caching mode .

Change batch size 1 in Destination.

Comment: Why do you suggest using No Caching mode?  The three modes are available for a reason, and No Caching is not always the appropriate one to use.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes/

Comment: we need to do insert and lookup on same table data if it is cached  there are possibility of duplicate data can inserted ..

Comment: You're right that Full Cache shouldn't be used in this situation, as new inserts will be undetected and result in repeated insert attempts for the same missing row.  But for an INSERT-only operation, Partial Cache won't cause this problem, and will perform better than No Cache.

Comment: you can try Partial Cache but safest way is no cache